My "online girlfriend" is asking me to convert incoming money on Cash App into bitcoin for her. Is it a scam?
My online girlfriend has people send me money through Cash App. I then buy bitcoin and send it to her. Is this a scam? When I met her online she wanted me to download Cash App which I never used before and she said it's her dad sending her money he sent over 1000.00 in just a couple months but I asked her why she doesn't have the Cash App she said she can't.

You're being used as a mule. The money you're receiving is originating from other scams or thefts and you're being used to launder it.

Two questions to ask: Does it involve money? Yes Do you think it may be a scam? Yes Then the answer 99.9% of the time to the question "Is it a scam" is Yes.

I'm curious. I have read the first fifty questions about this and the like. So, simply put: Why in the world would you NOT think it is a scam?

Your "girlfriend" is probably a guy in a scam factory in Nigeria or India who is using a few dozen other people like you as mules.

If you can send her Bitcoin, her dad can send her Bitcoin too. For that matter, he could send her a check or use Zelle or use one of a million other ways of transferring money. There's no plausible reason that they need you.

Yes, it's a scam. The money you've been sent will turn out to have been fraudulent, and those transfers will be reversed, so you’ll lose the money.

Either that, or you are being used to launder stolen money and are at risk of being charged for criminal activity. Or both. See many past questions tagged "scam"

Two questions to ask:

Does it involve money? Yes
Do you think it may be a scam? Yes

Then the answer 99.9% of the time to the question "Is it a scam" is Yes.
The "online girlfriend" part makes it 100%.
